# org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod on auth.log

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, log, dbus

My `auth.log` is full with error messages of `freedesktop`, most of them look more or less as follows:

```
May 25 07:59:40 lati dbus[425]: message repeated 7 times: [ [system] Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.63" (uid=1000 pid=2218 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=503 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")]
```

Any idea what that could be?

---

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-37-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14

Answer (score 1):

That message means that dbus rejected an error message (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod) pulseaudio tried to send to bluetoothd, probably because bluetoothd called an unknown method on pulseaudio's interface.

The strange thing is that error replies should be allowed (you should have `<allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="error"/>` in /etc/dbus-1/system.conf. I'm not sure if requested_reply="0" in your log indicates that pulseaudio does not declare the error message as a reply. That would be a bug in pulseaudio of course.

Comment: I have `<allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="method_return"/>` and `<allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="error"/>` there; is that enough?

Comment: Should be fine, yes. Maybe it's in fact a pulseaudio bug. I would try upgrading pulseaudio.